# react native map view : open specific annotation

Tags: javascript, mkmapview, react-native

Is there a way to open a specific annotation in a Mapview Component in react native :

I have the following component :

```
<MapView
  ref="mapview"
  style={styles.restaurantsMap}
  showsUserLocation={this.state.showsUserLocation}
  followUserLocation={false}
  annotations={_.map(this.state.data, (restaurant) => {
    return {
      latitude: restaurant.latitude,
      longitude: restaurant.longitude,
      title: restaurant.name,
      subtitle: restaurant.food[1]
    };
  })}
  region={this.state.center}
  onAnnotationPress={this.onAnnotationPress}
  onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete} />
```

I would like to have a function in the same class that opens a specific annotation, something like this :

```
openAnnotation = (id) => {
  // Opens the annotation with the specific id
}
```

Thanks